# CannotStartContainerError using AWS ECS with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

I have created a Task Definition based in EC2 instance with 4 containers and using default network mode. When I try to run it in my cluster I get the following status:

> STOPPED (CannotStartContainerError: Error response from dae)

If I go to see details of the error I get:

> CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:338: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: read init-p: connection

This is my Task Definition:

```json
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::102692121977:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/Greeting",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 8082,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8082
                }
            ],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 0,
            "environment": [],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": null,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "102692121977.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hamilton-greeting:latest",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "greeting"
        }
    ],
    "memory": "1",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::102692121977:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "family": "Greeting",
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "cpu": "1024",
    "inferenceAccelerators": [],
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "tags": []
}
```

I have already tried to add a `sh,-c` to the entrypoint of every container but it didn't work.

Comment: can you add your task definition?

Comment: @mreferre Yes, added already

Comment: There are some articles that pin down this problem to specific versions of Docker. It's hard to debug without doing some additional tests to root cause. What I would try: 
1- try to start the same docker image on the EC2 instance via a manual `docker run`
2- if you see the problem, try to check/upgrade the docker version on the EC2 instance 
3- try to create a new revision of the task def to deploy on Fargate (which uses containerd)